# Active Directory filter: mail not empty and don't ends with

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to write a filter to return users that have an mail adress but don't end with @global.local. I have tried this but it don't work

```
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(name=*)(mail=*)(!(mail=*@global.local))(objectClass=user))";
```

This will return users with @global.local. I assume that mail=* overrides (!(mail=*@global.local)). If I only use (!(mail=*@global.local)) then I will get users with mail = null.

I there a way to solve this with one query? Atm I'm removing @global.local in C# after the result is returned.

---

**Edit**

The above works, my problem was that I was looking at the wrong property. I should have been filtering on userPrincipalName instead of mail for the `@global.local` part.

Comment: This is not a C# question; it's at best a .NET question and maybe even not that since it's solely about writing an LDAP filter string.  Please rephrase and re-tag it so it will be relevant for future people searching for this who aren't C# specific.

Comment: You are correct,  edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your filter and it works properly with both, `(mail=*)` and without  as well as in c# and ldap tools. Try [LDAP Browser](http://www.ldapadministrator.com) and see what are the exact data there in the mail attribute and if queries behave in same manner.

Comment: I'm stupid, of course it works. My problem was that `@global.local` was not on the mail property but on the userPrincipalName property. Thanks for the help, it made me look again and see my error.